# How can I copy a large file to/from a network share in Windows without inflating the file cache? PowerShell or .NET, ideally

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am working with dedicated Windows 2008 R2 and 2003 SQL Servers; throughout the day and night I need to copy large files off the machines to network shares for backup and log shipping.

There's a documented issue where the OS will allocate a lot of memory to the file cache to handle these copies, and that robs memory, potentially, from other functions. (Eventually on Win2k8 R2, Task Manager reports Free Memory = 0 as the result of this behavior.) But these particular files are *never* read after the copy, and the "just in case" caching of the file data doesn't make sense for this function.

Is there a simple .NET or PowerShell way to copy files and not have this file cache grow? The biggest file I am dealing with, for reference, is 300+ GB.

We currently use RoboCopy on 2008 R2, xcopy on 2003, and SQL Server's own Log Shipping file copy job for this function.

I have heard about a /J switch in XCOPY in win2k8R2, and a special DLL from Exchange that some argue helps this issue but it would be nice to have a really clean and simple solution.

See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/11/27/too-much-cache.aspx

Comment: Have you tried Robocopy?

Comment: how is the copying task being done currently...? there are many ways to do it but one must show or display how the non robust code is currently working.

Comment: Edited to add current methods

Comment: What OS? If you have access to powershell v2, I would look at using it and BITs to do the transfer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/11/transferring-large-files-using-bits.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When I copy large amounts of data, I use Robocopy because I have run into problems with other options, e.g. XCOPY, Copy-Item, etc.

My Robocopy script:

```
#Source folder
$src = "" 

#Destination folder
$dest = "" 

<#Robocopy options: 
E = Copy subdirectories, including empty directories.
V = Verbose output
ZB = Restartable & backup mode (to handle network connectivity issues & disruptions)
COPY DAT = Copy Data, Attributes, and Timestamps. Add 'S' to include ACL/permissions.
XJ = Exclude junction points.
#>
$options = @("/E","/V","/ZB", "/COPY:DAT", "/XJ")

#Store src, dest, and other previously defined options in an array.
$cmdArgs = @($src, $dest, $options)

#Execute!
robocopy @cmdArgs
```